# Nested IF fails for Null

Tags: formula

```
Remaining_days__c = End_date__c - today();
```

End Date__c is Null in my required case, making Remaining Days as "Null-today()"

I am trying to make this work for a formula field, however its failing. Returns value "-" to Status__c, in case Remaining_days__c>90 which is satisfying the else condition, but returns value "Urgent" i.e. for Remaining_days__c<10, in case when we pass "End_Date__c-today()" in Remaining days, which should ideally pass in else condition.

```
Status__c=
IF(Remaining_Days__c <0 , "Late", 
IF(Remaining_Days__c <10, "Urgent", 
IF(Remaining_Days__c <30, "Soon", 
IF(Remaining_Days__c <90, "Started", "-"))))
```

Tried passing value by making Remaining Days as today()-today(), but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Check for the **remaining_days__c** field is **Null** value,if it not a Null value then perform your  **if else** condition otherwise just keep the value blank for status.Something like this.

Add formula to

```
Remaining_days__c = IF( ISNULL(End_date__c),null, End_date__c - today())
```

Also edited the field Remaining_days__c and status__c, You can see at the bottom 2 option 
select   **Treat blank fields as blanks**

Updated below code in Status__c formula field

```
IF(ISNULL( Remaining_days__c ) , "-",
IF(Remaining_days__c <= 0, "Late",
IF(Remaining_days__c < 10, "Urgent" ,
IF(Remaining_days__c < 30, "Soon",
IF(Remaining_days__c < 90,"Started", "-") ) ) ) )
```

Test 1 :

[image]

Test 2:

[image]

Field Snapshots
[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63558/discussion-on-answer-by-nithesh-k-nested-if-fails-for-null).